# Android screen too wide?

Tags: android, css

I am trying to create a small web app for my android device, I am testing it and there is a scrollbar on my screen (horizontal) no matter what i set the body width, I get the scrollbar. I noticed m.facebook.com doesn't have it. Do I just simply hide the scrollbar?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try :

```
webView.getSettings().setDefaultZoom(WebSettings.ZoomDensity.FAR);
```

^_^,pls check your AndroidManifest.xml

```
<uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="4" /><supports-screens 
          android:largeScreens="true"  
          android:normalScreens="true" 
          android:smallScreens="true" 
          android:anyDensity="true"  
    />
```

you must set android:anyDensity="true".

Answer (score 0):

Try setting `webView.setHorizontalScrollbarEnabled(false);` to your `WebView`

Answer (score 0):

Try `webView.setScrollBarStyle(WebView.SCROLLBARS_OUTSIDE_OVERLAY);` and it will add the scrollbar above the right edge of the WebView instead of making a theme colored line.